# Скачивание файлов в js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как написать скрипт для Tampermonkey, чтобы он при открытии новой вкладки в Firefox (например какой-либо картинки на сайте https://wallpaperscraft.ru) скачивал по ссылке с атрибутом href (например картинку в оригинальном разрешении) а потом закрывал эту вкладку.
Этот скрипт не работает.

```
     var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = sUrl;

    if (link.download !== undefined){
        //Set HTML5 download attribute. This will prevent file from opening if supported.
        var fileName = sUrl.substring(sUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, sUrl.length);
        link.download = fileName;
    }

    //Dispatching click event.
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        e.initEvent('click' ,true ,true);
        link.dispatchEvent(e);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Find link
var allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a'), sUrl;
for(let i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
    if(~allLinks[i].href.indexOf('.png')||~allLinks[i].href.indexOf('.jpg')) {
        // if it is image link, set sUrl
        sUrl = allLinks[i].href
    }
}
if(!sUrl) alert('Ссылка не найдена');
// Create another link
var link = document.createElement('a')
// Set href attribute
link.setAttribute('href',sUrl)
// Set html5 download attribute
link.setAttribute('download',sUrl.substring(sUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1,sUrl.length))
// Start download
link.click()
// Exit page
window.close()
// Проверено на Opera 62 - просто открывается ссылка, не понял причины. В Chrome 67 всё загружается
// Только там я в консоли увидел опечатку с window, но забыл исправить
```

Comment: в консоли пишет ReferenceError: sUrl is not defined Пробовал в Firefox 68.0.2

Comment: так я думал что уже объявлена переменная sUrl. Тогда сейчас изменю код.

Comment: А почему в Firefox не получается?

Comment: не устанавливается, какой-то dll просит, все обновления есть win10

Comment: Можно ли добавить, что бы при отсутствии ссылки с href он скачивал картинку по ссылке с атрибутом img? Просто на сайте deviantart не всегда есть возможность скачать картинку в оригинале.